# GPT HDD is only writable when formatted with NTFS, is read only with EXT4

Tags: ntfs, ext4, gpt, mbr

I have a 1TB sata gpt hdd that I removed from an apple time capsule and I am attempting to use it with Xubuntu 18.04. It initially had HFS+ partitions on it however I wiped those and made the whole drive one partition EXT4. Whenever I mounted it after that it would be read only. I then tried formatting it with NTFS. It is now writeable. Im wondering why EXT4 would not work and NTFS does? I dont know what dumps to include but here is fdisk -l

```
user@user:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for user: 
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00d600d6

Device     Boot     Start       End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        74088448 148172799 74084352 35.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       148174848 156301311  8126464  3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3  *         2048  74086032 74083985 35.3G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8448A6B2-15B3-11DD-9A21-001FF3C571C9

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00001441

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T 83 Linux
```

Comment: Did you give yourself ownership & permissions with chown & chmod commands? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: I did try "sudo chown -R user /media/user/1TB/" and "sudo chmod -R 777 /media/user/1TB/" when the drive was formatted with ext4 and I still could not write to the drive. I did not have to do either when it was formatted with ntfs. All formatting was done in gparted.

Comment: If you used "user" then that is the name of  the owner, user. You can use $USER or your actual login name.  to see contents of system variable $USER `echo $USER` And you should not use 777 as that gives the entire world access to  your system.  Use this; ` sudo chmod -R a+rwX  /media/user/1TB`

Comment: The drive ended up being internally damaged. Thanks for all the help